# MySql: Why foreign key is null?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables. `users` and `post`. I want to use `users(id)` column (which is pk) as foreign key in `post(user_id)` column. I used:

```
ALTER TABLE post ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id);
```

and that action succeeded without any errors but I see only `null`  in `(user_id)` column. Do I miss something or what? Shouldn't it copy the `id` values from `users` table?

Comment: Copy how? How should the DB know which user posted what post? If the column contained `null` before then the DB can't fill it.

Comment: When I register a new user and make a new post it still shows `null`. What should I do then to know which user made that post?

Comment: Foreign keys can be `NULL`.  Primary keys cannot be.

Comment: I want my foreign keys to show only `id` from `users` table. Not `null` or something else. :) Is it not possible?

Comment: You need to add the userId in your insert statements of your posts

Comment: @juergend I think I understand what you mean but my insert statement looks like this: `"INSERT INTO post (title, entry) values (?,?)"` How do I insert user id in here?

Comment: @oxyt: Hard to say without the code around it. If you have the user id  before calling the insertion then just change it to `INSERT INTO post (title, entry, user_id) values (?,?,?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:** Why foreign key is null?

**A:** Whether or not a column can contain a NULL value is determined by the presence or absence of a NOT NULL constraint. This is entirely independent of whether the column is referenced in a foreign key constraint.

The value in the column is NULL because that's the value that was assigned when the row was inserted. The value was assigned, whether it was explicitly set, or whether it was derived from the default value for the column.  (If the column was added to an existing table, then the values in the new column was the default value for the column.)

--

**Q:** Do I miss something or what?

**A:** The behavior and results you observe are exactly as we expect.

**Q:** Shouldn't it copy the id values from users table?

**A:** If you're asking if MySQL should automatically populate the `user_id` column in the `post` table, the answer to that question is no, it shouldn't.

I think maybe you've clued in on a key idea:

The "relationship" between a row in one table to a row in another table is represented in the relational database by storing a common value.

But the database doesn't know which row is related to which row. You have to tell it. You have to provide that information.

When you insert a row into the `post` table, you can provide a value for the `user_id` column. You would provide a value that's equal to the `id` value of some row in `user`.

The idea with a FOREIGN KEY constraint is that it's restriction. It only allows valid values. It prevents an invalid value from being stored. (That's true with InnoDB if FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1, that's not true for MyISAM, because MyISAM doesn't enforce foreign key constraints.)

The foreign key is saying that you want to "constrain" the values that can be stored. It's saying that it's not going to allow rows in `post` to have have `user_id` values that point to a "missing" row in the `users` table.

It's perfectly acceptable to store a `NULL` in a foreign key column. When a `NULL` value is stored, that's saying that the row is *not* related to a row in the `users` table.

Disallowing NULL values in a column is done with a different kind of constraint, a NOT NULL constraint.

It's possible to define *both* a foreign key constraint *and* a NOT NULL constraint on the same column. That's a design decision, whether you want to allow NULL values or not. In some cases, we may want to disallow NULL values in a foreign key. For example, if we were to add a NOT NULL constraint on the `user_id` column of `post`, that would effectively be saying that a row cannot exist in `post` if it's not related to a row in `users`. And that's a very common pattern.

Answer (score -1):

Adding foreign key to any column in MySQL does not copy any values.